# How to implement a nested query using loopback-sdk-builder?

Tags: angular, loopback

I have three loopback.js models:

- Client
- Subcription
- Category

These models are linked by a 'has many' type relation. That means that on each subscription, I have an Id pointing to the Client model and an Id pointing to the Category model.

On the Client, sdk-builder generates a method called `getSubscriptions`:
Defined like:

```
public getSubscriptions(id: any, filter: LoopBackFilter = {}, customHeaders?: Function): Observable<any> {
  let _method: string = "GET";
  let _url: string = LoopBackConfig.getPath() + "/" + LoopBackConfig.getApiVersion() +
"/Clients/:id/subscriptions";
  let _routeParams: any = {
  id: id
};
  let _postBody: any = {};
  let _urlParams: any = {};
if (typeof filter !== 'undefined' && filter !== null) _urlParams.filter = filter;
let result = this.request(_method, _url, _routeParams, _urlParams, _postBody, null, customHeaders);
return result;
```

}

When I run this method, I have an observable with the whole list of Subscription for this Client.

My problem is that in this list, I have Categories Ids. I would like to request the Category model to get Category names.

Nesting requests ( Doing another find on each row returned by the first subscribe() ) here is not an option as it would generate tons of HTTP requests.

Has someone any idea on how to implement this?

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved using the 'include' filter like in the below code line:

```
  this.souscription.find({include: {relation: 'category'}})
```